# Help identify this plant please

Tags: identification, safety

[image]

I was given this which is a small bush in a pot. I was told it was a climber but the giver doesn't remember what it is. However my puppy got hold of some earlier and ate it and since then has been quite sick. Need an identification so I can know whether it's serious enough to warrant an emergency call out for the vet. Thanks![image]

Comment: Do the flowers have a scent? I would expect it to be quite strong...

Answer (score 2):

I’m going out on a limb here, but the compound leaves with the significantly larger one at the tip plus the overall appearance of plant and flowers tell me that you have a [pink jasmine (look at the buds) or *Jasminum polyanthum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasminum_polyanthum).

I would have expected the flowers to be wider open, the tips of the petals forming a plane or even slightly bending backwards, but it may be that they are not yet fully in bloom. They should have a very distinctive sweet jasmine scent (hence my comment above).

Sources vary whether the plant is poisonous, but even those that claim its theoretically not, recommended keeping pets away from them and in case of ingestion, to monitor them closely.

> **Regardles of an id:
>
>   When a pet shows any signs of discomfort or sickness after ingesting anything suspicious, call your vet!**